# Dynamic sorting using Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>>

Tags: c#, sorting, .net-core, dynamic-linq

i want to query result and display in order based on Id,Nam,Phone and Email can anyone help me how to do it.
expected result

```
table1result=> table1.OrderBy(c => c.Id).ThenBy(c => c.Name).ThenBy(c => c.table2.Name).ThenBy(c=>c.table2.Phone)
```

below is sample code which results in

```
  Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderExpression = o => o.OrderBy(a => a.Id);
switch(case)
{
 case "Id" : orderExpression = o => o.OrderBy(a => a.Id);
break;
    case "name" : orderExpression = o => o.OrderBy(a => a.Name);
break;
   case "phone" : orderExpression = o => o.OrderBy(a => a.table2.phone);
break;
.
.
.
.
}
which result in 
table1result=> table1.OrderBy(a => a.Id);
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an `IQueryable<T>` extension and maybe that would help in your case:

```cs
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> SortBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, 
        IEnumerable<string> fieldsToSort)
    {
        Expression expression = source.Expression;
        bool firstTime = true;

        foreach (var f in fieldsToSort)
        {
            // { x }
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");

            // { x.FIELD }, e.g, { x.ID }, { x.Name }, etc
            var selector = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, f);

            // { x => x.FIELD }
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda(selector, parameter);

            // You can include sorting directions for advanced cases
            var method = firstTime
                ? "OrderBy" 
                : "ThenBy";

            // { OrderBy(x => x.FIELD) }
            expression = Expression.Call(
                typeof(Queryable), 
                method,
                new Type[] { source.ElementType, selector.Type },
                expression, 
                Expression.Quote(lambda)
            );

            firstTime = false;
        }

        return firstTime 
            ? source
            : source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(expression);
    }

}
```

So this extension method will apply the list of fields to sort on an `IQueryable` source with either "OrderBy" (if it's first time) or "ThenBy" (otherwise).

Then you can use it like:

```cs
var table1Result = table1
    .SortBy(new string[] { "Id", "Name", "Phone" });
```

Comment: Please update the code to handle both ASC & DESC order accordingly. It will be very helpful.

Comment: @NadimHossainSonet: you can kind of check out my other post (especially in Bonus section) about how to implement server side paging and searching with DataTables:https://stackoverflow.com/a/63000348/2410655. I think you can get some ideas from there.