# Asp.Net Razor Page DataTabels.net Jquery lazy loading data vom Database

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-core, datatables, razor-pages

i am working on a project for school. I am displaying data on a page with DataTabels.net Jquery. The page takes around 10 seconds to load because i dont know how i can use lazy loading with DataTabels.net.
I hope that someone could help me with this problem.

[This is how i load the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYZKg.png)

[How i display the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vG2ib.png)

[Script for the datatable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lU2Lt.png)

Comment: So my question is: Is there a way to load for example 100 rows and display them and load the rest of the data while i am on the site?

Comment: i will do it with datatables.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to load for example 100 rows and display them and load the rest of the data while i am on the site?

If you'd like to use jQuery DataTables to display large amounts of data, I really recommend that you can use the server-side options that DataTables provides, which would make all actions that DataTables performs (such as paging, searching and ordering) are handed off to a server.

Here is the doc about "Server-side processing": https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/

And you can refer to the following SO thread to implement same in your ASP.NET Core Razor pages project.

[How to implement dataTables Server side Side Paging/Searching/Sorting in ASP.net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62996638/how-to-implement-datatables-server-side-side-paging-searching-sorting-in-asp-net/63009124#63009124)

Comment: Will this increase the performance for my webpage? Because now it is loading 10 seconds to display all data, while loading them i cant do anything. It would be nice to see for example the 100 first records instand.

Comment: `Will this increase the performance for my webpage?` In my view, it would help improve the performance.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your anser. I will try to implemet server-side processing.